# Python saving string to file. Unicode error

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, utf

I am extracting data from a Google spreadsheet using Spreadsheet API in Python.  I can print every row of my spreadsheet on the commandline with a for loop but some of the text contain symbols e.g. celsius degree symbol(little circle).  As I print these rows on the commandline I want to write them to a file. But I get different unicode errors when I do this. I tried solving it by doing it manually but there are too many:

```
current=current.replace(u'\xa0',u'')
current=current.replace(u'\u000a',u'p')
current=current.replace(u'\u201c',u'\"')
current=current.replace(u'\u201d',u'\"')
current=current.replace(u'\u2014',u'-')
```

what can I do so I won't get errors?
e.g.

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 1394: ordinal not in range(128)

```
current=current.replace(u'\u0446',u'u')
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to decode it from whatever encoding it's in:

```
decoded_str = encoded_str.decode('utf-8')
```

For more information on how to deal with unicode strings, you should go over http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import unicodedata
decoded = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', encoded).decode('UTF-8', 'ignore')
```

I'm not quite sure that the normalize is needed in this case. Also, that ignore option means that you might loose some information, because decoding errors will be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

```
''.join(c for c in current if ord(c) < 128)
```

Comment: Not sure @TylerDurden wants to get rid of the `non-ascii` chararters !